# Laravel - Route [student] not defined

Tags: php, html, laravel, model-view-controller

I'm new to laravel..

and i got an error

**Route [student] not defined.**

this is the code in my view
`

```
<a href="{{ route('student', $student->id) }}" class="font-medium text-blue-600 dark:text-blue-500 hover:underline hover:text-blue-800 dark:hover:text-blue-400">
detail
</a>
```

`
this is the code in my controller

```
Route::get('/student/{id}', [
    'as' => 'student',
    StudentController::class,
    'ShowDetail',
]);
```

how do i fix it?

sorry my english is not very good, i don't know how to explain it
but
I want when "**detail**" is clicked it will move page to student/id or ( student/123 ) with **id** ,
then on the next page, it will display student data based on the id that was brought earlier

Comment: `'as' => 'student'` is the old syntax for naming routes. In more recent versions, you use `Route::get('/student/{id}', [StudentController::class, 'showDetail'])->name('student');` Please read the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#named-routes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
Route::get('/student/{id}', [StudentController::class, 'ShowDetail'])->name('student');
```

And calling the route with

```
<a href="{{ route('student', ['id' => $student->id]) }}"
```